# What are the limitations of SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How is this product limited in comparison to the other SKUs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [SQL Server Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx) page at Microsoft. Also this [Feature Comparison Chart](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx) at Microsoft.

Essentially:

- 1 CPU
- 4Gb maximum database size
- Unlimited users
- No SQL Server Agent support
- Still has support for procedures, triggers & functions
- Need Management Studio Express or Higher to manage the instance

Answer (score 1):

Per the [**product info page**](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx) (toward the bottom):

> SQL Server Express supports 1 physical
>   processor, 1 GB memory, and 4 GB
>   storage

Answer (score 0):

Is the 4 GB limit (which in R2's case has been increased to 10 GB), implies to total storage or per database?

Comment: it is per database.